# Typescript removes import statements not used in code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5, jspm

I am trying to use Typescript and jspm to make an angular app. The problem is when you want to ensure a `.js` file loaded, in jspm you have to write an import and it ensures the file will load before running your code. But Typescript removes my import. This is the Typescript code I have written. I have to load `angular-new-router` then add it to my module dependency.

```
import angular = require('angular');
import MainController = require('./controllers/MainController');
import NgNewRoute = require('angular-new-router');

console.log(angular.version);

var appModule = angular.module('app', ['ngNewRouter']);
MainController.register(appModule);

export = appModule;
```

My question: How can I instruct Typescript to not remove my import statement, Or I have to do something else to ensure my router loads?

**PS:** I compile my typescript code to ES5 with commonjs.

**EDIT:** This question is not the same as [TypeScript: import module with only statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455211/typescript-import-module-with-only-statements). I have this problem working with third party libraries, so I don't want to change them. Also I am using commonjs pattern so `amd-dependency` does not fix my problem!

**EDIT 2:** Another problem is I can not require files other than js modules in my Typescript code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeScript: import module with only statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455211/typescript-import-module-with-only-statements)

Comment: @sainaen: That is somehow related to my question but not completely. I am requiring third party libraries so that's not a good idea to change them to export a variable or sth.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer on that question is not the best one. See the other one, with more votes, it has a link to the official issue tracker with response from one the TypeScript team members and two possible workarounds, like it suggests that just referencing the imported module without doing anything with it may help.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I instruct Typescript to not remove my import statement, Or I have to do something else to ensure my router loads

You need to use something from the `import` as a variable e.g

```
import foo = require('./foo'); 
var bar = foo; // Like this
```

instead of just :

```
import foo = require('./foo'); 
var bar:foo; // This will not cause an import in the generated JavaScript
```

Comment: This is to support the use case of *lazy loading* : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Comment: I can't understand the relation of your answer to the provided link. The lazy loading use case is related to conditional loading of a type, but I want my to have angular library loaded before running it; Or I want to load a css file before my code runs.