# Nodejs: After Import of a module, code in the file is not getting executed

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am working on few files in nodejs app with **typescript**
Concerning files are as follows:
**some-module.ts**

```
console.log('inside some-module');
export default class Foo {
  /*...*/
}
/*execute some imp code*/
Injector.provideClass('Foo', Foo);
console.log('done with some-module');
```

**app.ts**

```
console.log('inside app.ts');
import Foo from './some-module'; // this does not execute console.log! Since Foo class is only referred and not actually used in app.ts file.
class App {
  static inject = ['Foo'];
  private foo: Foo;
  constructor(foo: Foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  /*...*/
}
Injector.injectClass(App); // This throws error as Foo is not provided in injector.
console.log('Done with app.ts');
```

**Output (console):**

```
$ inside app.ts
$ Done with app.ts
```

**Already tried:**

1. I have tried with `const Foo = require('./some-module');`, this works but its not the best way to do it in typescript. Since it does not recognize the types in it.
2. Also -> If if put imported Foo in console.log right after import statement then also it works. Since Foo is now getting used in imported module file.

```
import Foo from './some-module';
console.log(Foo); // <- After adding this simple log, it works!
```

3. Also -> If you do only import `import './some-module';`
   But this way you dont have access to its types.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using a bundler like webpack? Tree-shaking or similar performance focused logic might be limiting modules from running until they are needed.

Comment: What is `Injector` here? You're importing `Foo` from `./some_module` in `app.ts` but you're not exporting it in the `./some_module` file! If you just want to cause side effect from the `./some_module` then try using `import "./some_module".` But if you're exporting the `Foo` class then export it like `export default class Foo { ... }` in that module.

Comment: Oh wait you're exporting the class! Could you kindly try to provide us a reproducible example so that we can try it out ourselves to find out the problem?

Comment: @JDB Just typescript compiler `tsc`

Comment: @h-sifat consider `Injector.provideClass` and `Injector.injectClass` as some simple functions..

Comment: One explaination available here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16455992/17505616